# Помогите пожалуйста с django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Ошибка: 
ОШИБКА:  нулевое значение в столбце "shedule_id" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
DETAIL:  Ошибочная строка содержит (Ин.яз, Г-538, Евгений Борисович, 08:00:00, 11:10:00, 1, 1, 1, 1, null).

models.py:

```
class shedule(models.Model):
    shedule_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lesson = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classroom = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name_teacher = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    type_lesson = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    parity_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    day_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import shedule

type_lesson_choices = ((1, 'Практика'),
                (2, 'Лекция'))
parity_week_choices = ((1,'Нечетная'),
               (2, 'Четная'))
day_week_choices = ((1,'Понедельник'),
                    (2,'Вторник'),
                    (3,'Среда'),
                    (4,'Четверг'),
                    (5,'Пятница'),
                    (6,'Суббота'))


class AddLessonForm(ModelForm):
    lesson = forms.CharField(label='Название урока')
    name_teacher = forms.CharField(label='Имя учителя')
    start_time = forms.TimeField()
    end_time = forms.TimeField()
    classroom = forms.CharField(label='Аудитория')
    type_lesson = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=type_lesson_choices)
    parity_week = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=parity_week_choices)
    day_week = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=day_week_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = shedule
        fields = ('lesson', 'name_teacher', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'classroom', 'type_lesson', 'parity_week', 'day_week')
```

views.py

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddLessonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            lesson = form.save(commit=False)
            lesson.group = id_group
            lesson.save()
            return redirect('/shedule')
    else:
        form = AddLessonForm()
    return render(request, 'shedule/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Я понял что ошибка в том что он передает в Primary key null, хотя этого нельзя.
Как мне от него избавиться???
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил
Изменил в model.py

```
shedule_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Так первичные ключи можно вообще в модель не ставить. В чем смысл установки?